# Can you split the product of two functions of two variables into the sum of two others?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to design a set of functions to demonstrate a control algorithm I'm working on.

Does there exist a non-trivial $(v(x), f(y), w(x), g(y))$ such that $v\cdot w=f+g \; \forall (x,y)$? $x$ and $y$ are independent variables. By non-trivial, I mean that the four functions can't just be constants. Each of the functions maps real scalars to real scalars.

Comment: I guess you mean $v(x)w(y)=f(x)+g(y)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is $b$ so that $w(b)=0$, then
$f(x)+g(b)=v(x)w(b)=0$, this implies $f(x)=-g(b)$ is a constant: that is a "trivial" solution.

So assume $w(y)\neq 0$ for all $y$ and similarly, $v(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$.
Now
$$
\frac{f(x_1)+g(y)}{f(x_2)+g(y)}=\frac{v(x_1)w(y)}{v(x_2)w(y)}
=\frac{v(x_1)}{v(x_2)},
$$
If $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$, this equation implies $g(y)$ is a constant. So either $f$ or $g$ is a constant. So there is only "trivial" solutions.